# Bind the value into the function to avoid passing it to component explicitly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code which passes values of an array of objects down to a component.

```
{
  recipes.value.map((recipe) => (
    <RecipeBrowserItem
      key={"browse-item-" + recipe.nodeId}
      isMember={recipe.isMember}
      slug={recipe.slug}
      members={recipe.teamRecipe.nodes[0].recipeMembers.totalCount}
      teamRecipeId={recipe.teamRecipe.nodes[0].id}
      teamMemberId={identity.teamMemberId}
      onClickJoin={handleClickJoinRecipe}
    />
  ));
}
```

On the actual component the `onClickJoin` takes both `teamRecipeId` and `teamMemberId` so I am passing them down just to use a callback, can at least `teamRecipeId` be binded so that I don't have to pass it down?

I am basically just doing

```
const handleJoinRecipe = useCallback(() => {
    onClickJoin(teamRecipeId, teamMemberId);
}, [teamRecipeId, teamMemberId]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question you want to avoid explicitly passing down the props to the mapped `RecipeBrowserItem` components.

First off, wrapping these props in a `useCallback` hook in the child isn't the point of memoizing a callback. Generally you want to memoize the callback in the parent component that is passing it down as a callback to children via props.

It sounds like you want to create a curried callback that closes over the `identity.teamMemberId` value and later takes a specifically mapped element object's `recipe.teamRecipe.nodes[0].id` property.

The pattern for this usually looks similar to the following:

```
const handleClickJoinRecipe = (teamRecipeId) => () => {
  const teamMemberId = identity.teamMemberId; // <-- close over in scope
  ... additional shared variables/logic ...

  ... use the passed teamRecipeId argument ...

  ...
};
```

Example usage:

```
{recipes.value.map((recipe) => (
  <RecipeBrowserItem
    key={"browse-item-" + recipe.nodeId}
    isMember={recipe.isMember}
    slug={recipe.slug}
    members={recipe.teamRecipe.nodes[0].recipeMembers.totalCount}
    onClickJoin={handleClickJoinRecipe(recipe.teamRecipe.nodes[0].id)}
  />
))}
```

If you need to memoize the `handleClickJoinRecipe` callback, do it in the parent component, using the appropriate dependencies for the values you want to close over in callback scope when they update.

Example:

```
const handleClickJoinRecipe = useCallback((teamRecipeId) => () => {
  const teamMemberId = identity.teamMemberId; // <-- close over in scope
  ... additional shared variables/logic ...

  ... use the passed teamRecipeId argument ...

  ...
}, [identity.teamMemberId]);
```

The child component now only needs to attach the passed `onClickJoin` to an element's `onClick` handler, it doesn't need to pass anything.

```
onClick={onClickJoin}
```